# Query the product using Product Tag

Tags: graphql, shopify

I want to query the product using product tag, but it returned similar product tags with the given tags. I Refer some other references, it denotes the tag are tokenized field so it will return product, if any equality exists in the tags. but i want know if any possibility are there to retrieve the exact tag products

**Query**

```
query Myquery{
products(first:10, query: "tag:Switches variants.price:>=2335 variants.price:<=3000") {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        tags 
        variants(first:10)
        {
            edges
          {
            node
            {
                price 
            }
          }
        }
      }
      cursor
    }
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage
      hasPreviousPage
    }
  }
}
```

Above query returns tag 'Switches' and 'Switches & Sockets' but i need tag with 'Switches' alone

Answer (score 2):

You can add an exclusion but you need to know what to exclude e.g.:

```
{
  products(first:10, query: "tag:Switches -tag:Sockets") {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        tags 
        variants(first:10)
        {
            edges
          {
            node
            {
                price 
            }
          }
        }
      }
      cursor
    }
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage
      hasPreviousPage
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But on this page, only get the input switches how do i get rid of sockets

Comment: The above example excludes tags that contain Sockets, note the minus before `tag`. Have you tried that?

Comment: I Understood, @Vladimir but I'm not sure with Inputs. It may be `Switches & Sockets` or `Remote Switches` but how do i get rid of all tags and get `Switches` alone

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there's an input query that can return the products with exact tag. Only by excluding unwanted tags that you definitely know will appear in the results.

Comment: It's Ok @Vladimir Thank you for your valuable answer and time :)

Answer (score 0):

You understand that tags are a string right? So if you search for the string Switches you will get back Switches, and anything else in the string. So you have the extra step of further processing your results. Split on comma into an array, and only return the products where the filter condition is equal to Switches alone.

Comment: Sorry I'm not get your point, correct this was wrong, get the product and sorted out client end eg. Thro js